# Multiplying matrix with orthonormal columns by diagonal matrix $A'DA$

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

If $A$ is a $n\times k$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $D$ a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with positive entries. What properties does $(A'DA)^{-1} $ have? It's clear that it is a symmetric positive-definite matrix, and, due to the nature of the problem I found this in, I think it should also be a diagonal matrix, but I can't write a proof (maybe because it is not).

I realize that multiplying every column of $A$ by a different non-zero constant does preserve the orthogonality of its columns, is this also true for rows? Are the columns of $D^{1/2}A$ also orthogonal?

Comment: As to your last question: Why don't you just check that by examples?

Comment: $DA$ is $A$ with each row multiplied by the corresponding element of $D$.